# PDF Reader/editor in Ajax/ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am working on project that allows to read document within the browser without the need to install software , It's a part of a management application for companies.
I tried out to work with iTextSharp ,PDFSharp , but these labrories don't allows you to do what I want to do.It's just for generating pdf from HTML.
I checked out for another solution , I found an interesting project developed by Mozilla Lab . Mozilla is working on technology that will allow PDF documents to be rendered within the browser, rather than utilizing a browser plug-in or an external app to open them.
https://github.com/Marak/pdf.js/

I wonder to know Can I integer this script and use it with ASP.Net ? , If yes , I will be pleased to be guided by you with code source or external links that you recommend in order to implement this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that link you have sighted is about creating PDF file in browser (and not about showing existing PDF in browser).

Said that, there is another interesting project [pdf.js](http://andreasgal.com/2011/06/15/pdf-js/) that is trying to render PDF using java-script and HTML 5. Its essentially a java-script library that takes PDF bytes and attempt to render them. As such, you should able to integrate it in any web site regardless of server side technology - include the script and make relevant calls. See this [simple example](https://github.com/andreasgal/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/helloworld) to get started.

Comment: I think that you didn't understand the introduction , the link that you have posted is the same link that I have already shared . They are the same project ?

Comment: @TZano, perhaps, you have misunderstood. They are different projects with different goal and different github repositories - here's the url for one that I have sighted: https://github.com/andreasgal/pdf.js It's different than the one you have sighted. Did you see the example link - check hello.js.

Comment: Yes I have did , I am working on making notation on the PDF file , whitch project could help.

Comment: As I told you , the developer of the both project is the same one , he integrated the work that he did in the first in the second.

Comment: @Imasks, who is the *same* developer? As I see, there are two different persons who are maintaining the repositories. Further, the source code for `pdf.js` for both project is completely different. Anyway, as far as, your problem goes, I believe that you should use what I have sighted. You need to add your own UI on top of it to add notations. You may attempt to edit the original pdf byte stream but if that doesn't work, you can always submit notations data in some other form (JSON, HTML) and update the pdf on the server.